# how to refer to previous entry price in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I want to write an script in pine in which my short entry condition is related to my previous long entry price, how can I do it? for example short entry when price hits (1.1*previous long entry price)
so far I found out I can refer to previous candles price by "close[]" but couldn't find a way to refer to previous long entry price.

In the example below I don't know what to put instead of ? as a reference to previous long condition price.

```
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)

shortCondition = close >= 1.1 * ?
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.exit("sell", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strategy.position_avg_price 
gives you the average price for long and short entries

strategy.long / strategy.short 
gives you the price for long or short entries

Comment: yep, its exactly what i was looking for...thanks a lot,,great help

Comment: `strategy.long` is a boolean. How can it give price information?

Comment: I am dealing with something similar but different, to close/protect  Long position only when old price < than new price (close),  but how to do it in Pine ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386653/how-to-refer-to-previous-entry-price-stored-in-temp-variable-in-pinescript