# how to refer to previous entry price stored in temp variable in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I have some basic MA cross strategy indicator  and  I would like to implement better strategy, to sell only when price is higher than was bought before, but I am not sure how to do it in PINE syntax, any idea pls ?

Here is simple code, working fine this one, it open LONG or close LONG depends on cross MA :

```
// Strategy functions

if (crossover(outShort,outLong)) 
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)

if (crossunder(outShort,outLong)) 
    strategy.close(id="Long")
```

And here is my problematic code, I would like to implement to sell only when price is higher than was bought before,  so I added condition to check new price `price < close` , but not sure how to write in Pine syntax

```
// Strategy implemented - but with errors
var entryprice = 0

if (crossover(outShort,outLong)) 
    entryprice := close
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)


if (crossunder(outShort,outLong)) and ( entryprice < close )
    strategy.close(id="Long")
```

Here is screenshot, logic still not works as expected, if condition `entryprice < close` not works

[image]

Excelent, By the way do you know why my initial_capital value =1000 defined in strategy not correspond to the profit ? even if I change the capital number, profit show still same results.

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="My_MA_strategy", shorttitle="MyMA Strategy_0.04", format=format.price,  initial_capital=1000, overlay=true)
```

E.g. 1st trade show profit $154, even there is only 0,26% profit ( from 1000 capital not possible)
Percentage shows OK, but profit not.

[image]

Tried to change Market tpe , but no progress here, still show same profit

[image: MarektType]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var float price = 0.0
```

or

```
var float price = 0
```

or

```
var price = 0.
```

so that your variable is declared as type "float". The first, more explicit form is preferable because it declares your intent more clearly.

[EDIT 2021.05.06 10:34 — LucF]

The `if` block for entries should be entered only once, when there is no position, otherwise its condition can be true multiple times during a trade, and `entryprice` will change each time, which you do not want.

Use:

```
if (crossover(outShort,outLong)) and strategy.position_size == 0
```

Comment: OK, now I got no compile errors, but seems that logic still not works as expected, to not sell under price was bought before, I put screenshot above

Comment: Added an edit to the answer to restrict your entry conditions.

Comment: Excellent ! By the way do you know why  my initial_capital value =1000 defined in strategy not correspond to the profit ? even if I change the number ... profit show still same results, I put example in my above request

Comment: It can depend on the market you are running the strat on. Different markets have different minimum position sizes. Try making capital 1M.

Comment: Sorry I don;t understand what u mean market type, I have checking Crypto Prices from Exchange, but for Tradingview it does not matter, I hope,  its just a data. Anyway I found out that the price profit just show difference between original stock price, but not reflect my capital buy entry, is it even possible to show my profit in strategy ? I tried to change Market type in STrategy, also changed CApital to Million but no progress. I put examples above.

Comment: One more question, what if I want use pyramiding schema  to open another Long order? if price goes below my current position ? Because now with your help `strategy.position_size == 0` I fixed one issue to close position only in profit, but I am missing lot of trades to open when price goes below my current opened trade. In general all my next open Long is opening in Higher price than before order... So my goal is to keep opened more Long trades in paralel, but each trade to close only in profit.

Comment: OK, I open new question for this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541093/pine-how-open-more-long-orders-in-parallel-pyramiding