# Pine: How open more Long orders in parallel ? (pyramiding)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I have this Pine strategy to open Long position when MA cross, and close position only if close price is higher than open order and also I put condition to close only if profit is more than 2% `(((price/close)-1)*(-1)*100)>2`
Strategy works fine, orders are closed only in profit but issue is that many trades I am missing because in general due to my strategy each new Long starts in higher price then previos trade, So when price drops, no other Long is opened. I think this is job for pyramiding to open more orders, but how to do it ? Lets say if price drops 5% from last opened Long price,  then new Long order should be opened, when new buy signal is coming `(crossover(outShort,outLong)`

```
// Strategy functions
var  price = 0.0


if (crossover(outShort,outLong)) and afterStartDate and strategy.position_size == 0 and close < 59000
    price := close
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)
    


if (crossunder(outShort,outLong)) and afterStartDate and ( price < close ) and (((price/close)-1)*(-1)*100)>2
    strategy.close(id="Long")
```

Here is my full simple code.
By default strategy start in 1st May

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="My_MA_strategy", shorttitle="MyMA Strategy_0.04", format=format.price,  initial_capital=1000, overlay=true)

startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer,
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer,
     defval=5, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer,
     defval=2021, minval=1800, maxval=2100)
     
afterStartDate = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone,
     startYear, startMonth, startDate, 0, 0))
     

// Inputs
i_oversold      = input(30, title="Oversold")
i_overbought    = input(70, title="Overbought")
len             = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src             = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)



lenShort = input(10, minval=1, title="LengthShort")
srcShort = input(close, title="SourceShort")
offsetShort = input(title="OffsetShort", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
outShort = sma(srcShort, lenShort)
plot(outShort, color=color.green, title="MA_Short", offset=offsetShort)


lenLong = input(19, minval=1, title="LengthLong")
srcLong = input(close, title="SourceLong")
offsetLong = input(title="OffsetLong", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
outLong = sma(srcLong, lenLong)
plot(outLong, color=color.red, title="MA_Long", offset=offsetLong)



// Strategy functions
var  price = 0.0


if (crossover(outShort,outLong)) and afterStartDate and strategy.position_size == 0
    price := close
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)
    

if (crossunder(outShort,outLong)) and afterStartDate and ( price < close )
    strategy.close(id="Long")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to declare pyramiding in your strategy.

> pyramiding (const integer) The maximum number of entries allowed in
> the same direction. If the value is 0, only one entry order in the
> same direction can be opened, and additional entry orders are
> rejected. The default value is 0.

```
strategy(title="MyStrategy", shorttitle="MS", pyramiding = 10)
```

Comment: yes , I already used pyramiding const, but it has no result probably due to my open Long condition `...strategy.position_size == 0`, but I used this condition to achieve open and close order in profit... so probably I have to somehow modify my open Long condition code

Comment: ah ok, if position size is zero, i confirm not working.  You have to declare some value in order to proper calculate strategy.

Comment: Problem is when I changed the value to e.g. `position_size == 1`, then I got result : no data, no order was found.  Other way, when I changed to `position_size  >=0 ` then I got more Long trades, but also the close position condition is somehow ignoring  `(price < close)` , and it close also in loss,  so I am stuck here.